# Is it true that $\mathbb{E}_B[\mathbb{E}_{A|B} [g(A,B) | B]]=\mathbb{E}_A[\mathbb{E}_{B|A}[g(A,B)|A]]$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Take a function $g$ of two random variable $A$, $B$ which are not necessarily independent. Is the following true:
$$
\mathbb{E}_B\big[\mathbb{E}_{A|B} [g(A,B) | B]\big] = \mathbb{E}_A\big[\mathbb{E}_{B|A}[g(A,B)|A]\big]\,? 
$$

Comment: This is pretty straightforward to show.  Try starting by expanding the expectation of the joint (i.e E(g(A,B)), and use the multiplicative law of probability to obtain the expression on the right and the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. For a clearer exposition, assume $A$ and $B$ are defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$. Because the sample space $\Omega$ belongs to both $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$, by definition of expectation (the first equality) and the conditional expectation (the second equality), it follows that:
\begin{align}
& E[E[g(A, B) | B]] = \int_\Omega E[g(A, B) | B] dP = \int_\Omega g(A, B) dP = E[g(A, B)], \\
& E[E[g(A, B) | A]] = \int_\Omega E[g(A, B) | A] dP = \int_\Omega g(A, B) dP = E[g(A, B)].
\end{align}

Note the subscripts "$A, B, A | B, B | A$" may be safely dropped by keeping in mind your calculation is done on the original probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, instead of on the induced probability spaces.

In fact, this is a direct application of the well-known iterative expectation law: for any integrable random variable $X$ and a sub-$\sigma$ algebra $\mathscr{G}$:
$$E[E[X | \mathscr{G}]] = E[X].$$